A smart way to ground yourself to help a person who is being shocked by electricity
:)
I am currently planning a scene for my fantasy novel that involves electricity. I'm unsure if regular electricity with its properties known to us works in the context of my magical world or if I have to change it up a little, but this is the setup:
V = villain
A = Person who is one ground, being shocked
B = person who tries to help person A
So, V is capable of generating electricity. They can "shoot" it at others to shock them, making the hit person unable to move. They also have a static field around them that makes it difficult to attack them. Now, A is being shocked by V, and B needs a smart way to help A without getting shocked themselves. I thought it might work when B interrupts the ongoing stream of electricity by pushing a sword into the ground in its path, and therefore discharging the attack, but I find that a little anticlimactic. Throwing something at V to interrupt them doesn't work because of a protective magic shield around them, so B needs something to help A instead of attacking. My other idea would be that the ground is wet from a rainstorm, for example, and B pushes a knife with a metal grip into the ground to be able to touch A and drag them away, but I don't know if that would even work.
Helping character B knows what electricity is, they have a past in which they had to deal with attacks using electricity, but both A and B were completely unaware that V would/could use electricity in this way before the fight started, so they can improvise, but not prepare.  There is no rubber or plastic in this world, but there are celestial weapons that are conductors and can also store a little of the energy they are hit with, including electricity.
Because I didn't explain well enough what I'm looking for before editing this post, I'll try to clarify:
I'm not looking for ideas on how this scene plays out, I'm currently researching about electricity, how to discharge it, how it behaves in specific situations, grounding etc. to check if my idea is already faulty at its base or if there is a chance that I can make it work.
Depending on how "real" electricity would behave in this very specific situation, I would then change up the "magical" one I'm currently working on to make sure the scene can play out as I'd like it to.
Thank you!!

Welcome to worldbuilding. We don't help you with developing your story, which is what you are asking. We help with the rules of your fictional world. You can read more in the [help]

The one thing you do not want to do when touching a live conductor is to ground yourself. On the contrary, what you want to do is to make sure that you are insulated from the ground, for example by wearing boots with thick rubber soles. You do not want to give the current a path through your body to the ground. That being said, I have no idea what the Villain is actually doing to poor Afflicted, so that I can form no cogent proposal for the action of the gracious Bailer.

As @AlexP said, this is completely backwards. People who deal with electricity all the time would 1. wear insulated boots 2. use one hand to extract somebody who is being shocked. Electricity travels through the path of least resistance, so if you have insulated boots, there is more resistance from your hand to the ground. Therefore, electricity won't flow in that direction. If you use two hands, then electricity would flow between them (start at one hand, through the chest, out the other. Most likely affecting your heart). But with one hand at most it will shock your palm.

Also, assuming A/B are aware of electricity and that they'd be facing somebody who controls electricity, I'd expect them to pack some plastic and rubber tools. Or anything else non-conductive. You can extract somebody who is being shocked out of that situation by using a broom handle or whatever is available.

Thank you for your replies! :) Rubber doesn't exist in this world, and A/B were not aware of the villain's powers up to the point when the fight begins.  They have to improvise, and I think that I found a solution that combines what you said with my magic system. Thanks to all!

You lift yourself. And then you bond on to be at the same potential as the current. - They can levitate, right? Otherwise, maybe sit this one out. ... "FLOAT!"

You don't know much about how electricity works, your sword-wielding characters probably haven't even heard of it, and your audience won't know more about the villain's magic powers than you tell them. I'd highly recommend making the villain use electricity-flavored magical mystery energy and specifying its abilities and constraints yourself. You can - and without a year or so of serious training, will - be wrong about the abilities and constraints of electricity, and even if you aren't they're not likely to be the just-right abilities and constraints for your story.

Although if you were writing a modern-day thriller about a detective pursuing a serial killer electrician, that would be pretty awesome actually.

It has boiled down to essentially that :) It is a magically fueled form of electricity that will be dealt with using fictional weapons.  It has some properties of the electricity we know, but I think it should be like you said: its own thing in its own world. Thanks!

I'm not sure what you're asking: are you looking for feedback on the scenario you're sketching? If you're looking to find out how electricity works, this is not the right site, and, as you yourself seem to suggest with your edit, you can't ask us what your characters would do, either.

More or less feedback, yes. I'd just like to know if my scenario in itself works at its base or if I have to change it fundamentally

Person B cannot ground themselves. They should seek to ground out the stream of electricity.
I can't emphasize @AlexP's comments enough. It's a very bad idea to try and ground yourself when working with electricity for the purpose of intentionally shunting the electricity. Too much of your body is water and while skin has a fairly high natural resistance, all you need is for that jolt to cross your chest or across a major organ and you're dead as a door nail. To give you a real idea, electrical lineman is one of the most dangerous jobs on Earth. Therefore, unless it's a rule of your world that something magical is protecting person B (e.g., electrically resistant armor), it's unbelievable that they could lift person A out of the way (and it's irresponsible to do so in a Real World "believable" way... heaven forbid that one of your readers might try it thinking you knew what you were talking about, I'll talk about that momentarily).
Barring some magical protection, you don't want to get directly involved with the electricity at all. If you want to be cool, you want to discharge the electricity away from person A.
Magic & Physics
Your world has magic. Mixing magic with physics is difficult at the best of times, but let's try anyway.
From a physics standpoint, the only way an electrical attack has any hope of actually working is for the target of the magic to magically have the lowest voltage potential in the area. That electrical potential must be lower than any nearby bodies of water (including streams, aqueducts and pipes), lower than any nearby metal, even lower than the earth beneath their feet. Either that, or the magic must create such a point behind the target so that the electricity passes through the victim. Simplifying a bit, this is what happens when people are struck by lightning. They have the misfortune of being in the way when the electricity passes through them to the lowest voltage potential in the area.
I don't care how your magic does this, I only care that it does it. Here's why...
You might not like the idea of driving the sword into the ground, but that's (from a practical perspective) what you have to do. Person B must drive an entirely conductive sword into something that's an even lower voltage potential than the spot created by magic.
This isn't unreasonable. Electricity will pass through air more easily than it will through dirt. If the magic creates a "just low enough" potential point behind the target (or even doing this to the victim themselves), then person A can realize that there is an underground water source (pipe... aqueduct... cistern...) and then penetrate to that source using the sword. Personally, I'm fond of an underground stream of mercury. Make sure you explain why it's there after the fact (or early enough in the story that people have kinda forgotten about it by this encounter).
The primary story element isn't the sword, it's the logical existence of the water/something source, which would (could/must be) a lower voltage potential than the spot created by magic. This would believably divert the magic for the duration of the spell.
Let me conclude by reiterating politely what others have said a bit more brutally
There's a creative writing axiom that you're ignoring: write about what you know.
It's not uncommon for authors to tackle subjects they're initially unfamiliar with. Authors frequently perform a great deal of research to complete their stories. They learn about what they don't know so they can write about what they do know.
You need to learn more about electricity: how it works and why it works. By asking here as you have you're expecting us to either educate you or skip the education. Frankly, you can't let that happen. If you don't understand what you're trying to do, then you can't judge the quality of the answer (you can't even judge if we know what we're talking about).
My family and I ran a micropublisher for a decade. We've worked with hundreds of authors and read tens of thousands of story proposals. Lucky authors crank out a story in under a year and make money. Good authors take 1-5 years to produce a great story. Most of that time is spent learning to know what to write.
Don't get into the habit of skipping the research period. You need to know everything about the world you're writing about insofar as it's needed for the story. We can help you create and consistently use world rules, but never trust us to be the research you're not willing to do. Fair warning.

Thanks so much for the lengthy reply! You are completely right. That scene is more of an idea that is not fully developed yet, and as part of my research I stumbled across this forum. I might have phrased what I needed a little weirdly, I wasn't actually looking for someone to do the research for me or come up with something the character could do, I just wanted to know if my idea was already faulty at its very base or if I could potentially make it work once I've learned more.  It's all still very rough, but I'm slowly getting there. Thanks!
